# How do you make numbers 1 - 100 using the digits "2 0 2 4"?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I'm trying to complete this "2024 Challenge", but I'm still missing quite a lot of numbers. I need your help to finish this challenge. All answers are appreciated.

Rules:

Use all 4 digits **exactly ONCE!**

Allowed operations you can use: +, -, x, /, ! (factorial), !! (double factorial), a^b (exponentiation), √ (square root).

Brackets & concatenation are allowed (e.g. 20/(2*4)).

Squaring uses the number 2.

Rounding is **NOT** allowed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions from ongoing contests are banned](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/69582).

Comment: Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Is this part of a contest or homework or just an activity for fun or something else?

Comment: Deleting the part of the question where you admit it's a contest, doesn't suddenly make the question acceptable - it actually makes it worse, since it seems you're trying to hide something.

Comment: You could instead add more details to explain why this *doesn't* fall under the policy which I linked in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got through 30 before I saw that comment about questions for ongoing contests being banned...

> 1 = (2+2+0)/4 
>   2 = 2+(2×0×4) 
>   3 = 4-(2/2)+0 
>   4 = (2×4)/2+0  
>   5 = 4+(2/2)+0 
>   6 = (2×0)+2+4 
>   7 = (2^0)+2+4 
>   8 = 2+0+2+4 
>   9 = (2^0)+2×4 
>  10 = (2+0)+2×4 
>  11 = 0!+2+2×4 
>  12 = [(2+2)-0!]*4  
>  13 = (4^2)-2-0! 
>  14 = (4^2)-2×0! 
>  15 = (4^2)-2/0! 
>  16 = 2×0+2^4 
>  17 = 2×2×4+0! 
>  18 = (2+0!)×(2+4) 
>  19 = 4!-2-2-0! 
>  20 = (2+0!+2)×4 
>  21 = 4!-(2+2-0!) 
>  22 = 4!-2-(2×0) 
>  23 = 4!-2/2-0 
>  24 = 4!+(2×2×0) 
>  25 = 4!+(2/2)+0 
>  26 = 4!+2+2×0 
>  27 = 4!+2+(2-0!) 
>  28 = 4!+2+2+0 
>  29 = 4!+2+2+0! 
>  30 = 4!+[2×(2+0!)]

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm missing a lot of numbers, I have numbers 1 - 30.

1 = (2+2+4)^0

2 = [(4*2)*0]+2

3 = [(4+2)/2]+0

4 = (4+2+0)-2

5 = (2/2)+(4+0)

6 = (2*0)+(2+4)

7 = (20/4)+2

8 = 2+0+2+4

9 = 2^0+(2*4)

10 = [(2*4)+2]+0

11 = [(2*4)+2]+0!

12 = (4!!+2^2)+0

13 = [(2+0!)^2]+4

14 = 2(0!+2+4)

15 = (4^2)-(2^0)

16 = 4[(2^2)*0!]

17 = (4^2)+(2^0)

18 = [(4^2)+2]*0!

19 = (40-2)/2

20 = 4!-[(2^2)+0]

21 = 4!-[(2^0)+2]

22 = 4!-2-(2*0)

23 = 4!-(22^0)

24 = 4!+(22*0)

25 = 4!+(22^0)

26 = 24+(2+0)

27 = 4!+[(2^2)-(0!)]

28 = 4!+[(2^2)-0]

29 = 4!+[(2^2)+(0!)]

30 = 5!/4 (2*2+0!=5)